# How to solve Missing Return Value Error Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that counts the number of sevens in an array, whenever I run it, I get the error: incompatible types, missing return value. I'm not too sure where I have gone wrong.

```
int count_seven = 0;
        for(int n = 0; n < nums.length; n++){
            if(nums[n] == 7){
                count_seven++;
            }
                return count_seven;
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: you're probably missing the return statement at the end. Also, it would be great to see the full method implementation to help you with that.

Comment: your `return count_seven;` is inside the for loop. it should be below the loop

Comment: Also, your return count_seven should probably be after your for, and not in it